# How to bootstrap modal popup after submmision and redirect

Tags: php, phpmailer

Hello I Have Contact us Page like this

```
<form id="contact_form" action="sendmail.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <div class="row">
        <label for="name">Your name:</label><br />
        <input id="name" class="input" name="name" type="text" value="" size="30" /><br />
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <label for="email">Your email:</label><br />
        <input id="email" class="input" name="email" type="text" value="" size="30" /><br />
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <label for="message">Your message:</label><br />
        <textarea id="message" class="input" name="message" rows="7" cols="30"></textarea><br />
    </div>
    <input id="submit_button" type="submit" value="Send email" />
</form>
```

My send mail.php like this

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['email'])) {
    $subject = "Contact Us Form";
    $name = $_POST['name']; // required
    $email_from = $_POST['email']; // required
    $Enquiry=$_POST['message']; // required
    $message = '<html><body>';
    $message .= '<img src="http://inncrotech.com/migration/wp-content/uploads/2017/01/LGD4.png" alt="Website Change Request" />';
    $message .= '<table rules="all" style="border-color: #666;" cellpadding="10">';
    $message .= "<tr style='background: #eee;'><td><strong>Name:</strong> </td><td>" . strip_tags($name) . "</td></tr>";
    $message .= "<tr style='background: #eee;'><td><strong>Email:</strong> </td><td>" . strip_tags($email_from) . "</td></tr>";
    $message .= "<tr style='background: #eee;'><td><strong>Enquiry:</strong> </td><td>" . strip_tags($Enquiry) . "</td></tr>";
    $message .= "</table>";
    $message .= "</body></html>";
    $to = "somone@edgemigration.com.au";
    $header = "From:team@inncrotech.site \r\n";
    $header .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
    $header .= "Content-type: text/html\r\n";
    $retval = mail ($to,$subject,$message,$header);
    if( $retval == true ) {
        header('Location: http://abc.website/contact-us?status=success');
    }else {
        header('Location: http://abc.website/contact-us?status=fail');
    }
}
?>
```

And I am Showing success message on contact us form like this

```
<?php
$status=$_GET['status'];
if($status=='success') 
{
?>
<p style="color: green;background-color: #DFF2BF;text-align:center;">
    <?php echo 'Email sent';  ?></p>
<?php } ?>
```

I wanted to show **bootstrap modal popup** on Contact Us page

please help me in that Thanks in advance

Comment: What difficulty are you having with it? Did you see the [documentation](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals)? It shows you how to show a modal popup there. Come back when you have a more specific question.

Comment: Hello @shankar can you please give some more details, In which you want to open `Modal` and what you had try for this ?

Comment: Do you want to show model popup document onload?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to use bootstrap modal on your page but you are writing normal html structure for it.

If you want model then you have to write the bootstrap modal structure.

Please check this link.

http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals